# Will mongoDB reuse the space after I drop a collection?

Tags: mongodb

First of all, I know that we should run a 'compact' or 'repariDatabase' command if we want mongoDB to release disk space to OS after a 'delete' or 'drop' executed.

For my situation, I don't care the disk sapce is still ocuppied by mongoDB if mongoDB can reuse the space to store new collection.

For example, there is a 50GB collection named "collection-Jan", after I drop "collection-Jan", what would happen if a 60GB "collection-Nov" save into the same DB?

P.S., my mongoDB version is 4.2.13

Comment: Each collection/index is store in a file. If you drop a collection then this file is deleted from the filesystem. So yes, the space is released.

Comment: Also see, [How do I reclaim disk space in WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-reclaim-disk-space-in-wiredtiger-)

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Thanks a lot! I test this on my mongo, this is much more convenient than SQL SERVER.